# Jedi python is not installing while installing packages from requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, jedi, jedi-vim

I have created a virtual environment with python 3.6 on my ubuntu18 system. But while installing requirements.txt file using the command like 'pip install -r requirements.txt' for a project, I have got the error like below:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jedi==0.15.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25)) (from versions: 0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jedi==0.15.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25)
```

Not sure why it is not satisfies jedi in the requirements file.

Below is the requirements.text file

```
appnope==0.1.0
attrs==19.1.0 
backcall==0.1.0
bcrypt==3.1.7
bleach==3.1.0
cffi==1.13.1
Click==7.0
decorator==4.4.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
dnspython==1.15.0
entrypoints==0.3
Faker==0.8.13
flake8==3.7.8
Flask==0.12.4
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.3
Flask-JWT-Extended==3.7.0
Flask-Login==0.4.0
importlib-metadata==0.23
ipykernel==5.1.3
ipython==7.8.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.15.1
Jinja2==2.10.3
jsonschema==3.1.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.3.1
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
more-itertools==7.2.0
nbconvert==5.6.0
nbformat==4.4.0
notebook==6.0.1
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.5.1
pexpect==4.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pluggy==0.6.0
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==2.0.10
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py==1.8.0
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pycparser==2.19
pyflakes==2.1.1
Pygments==2.4.2
PyJWT==1.7.1
pymongo==3.7.2
pyrsistent==0.15.4
pytest==3.3.0
pytest-flask==0.11.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pyzmq==18.1.0
qtconsole==4.5.5 
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.12.0
terminado==0.8.2
testpath==0.4.2
text-unidecode==1.2
tornado==6.0.3
traitlets==4.3.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.16.0
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
zipp==0.6.0
```

Any suggestion are appreciable Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the setup requirements for [Jedi 0.15.1](https://pypi.org/project/jedi/0.15.1/), this should be installable on Python versions 2.7 and above, excluding 3.0.x through 3.3.x:

[`python_requires='>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*'`](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/blob/005f69390c4b1a3b864e7373cfcbdaf95e65411d/setup.py#L36)

I would suspect that you aren't actually running `pip` on the Python version you assume. I just tried on my machine running Python 3.7.5 and had no issues running `pip install jedi==0.15.1`.

You can find out what environment pip is running under with the following command.

[`pip --version`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#cmdoption-version)

Comment: pip is running under python3.6. when I run pip --version it is showing "pip 20.1.1 from /home/shubham/Documents/projects/m220/mflix_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
".

Comment: This might be a bug then, and you should likely report this to the team behind Jedi. The only mention I can find of Python 3.6 on their issues right now is the following, which was fixed in 0.17.1 according to the linked commit: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1224

Comment: I'd also recommend just trying to install a different version of Jedi, just to see if it's a specific version issue, or if there's a wider problem (I'd recommend the latest, just don't pass a version identifier to pip). If the latest doesn't work for you either, it's likely there's a mystery problem with your Python configuration.